# Executable file is not running in vista

Tags: windows

I have an executable file which is .net 4.0 framework compatible.
When i am running it into windows 7 it is running normally, but when i tried to run it on windows vista then it is not running.
Please tell me is it possible to run 4.0 framework application on vista?
If yes then how, if not then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was because of some dll files difference between windows 7 and windows vista.
i got them and solved.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the executable fails to run because its dependency on .net 4 is not being met. Vista comes with .net 3 installed, but no later version. Which makes sense because Vista pre-dates .net 4 by many years.

Install the .net 4 runtime on the machine to resolve the problem.